# Disable screen offset when displaying the software keyboard

Tags: android, c++, ios, qt, qml

Project qml / c ++ for Android / iOS. When the software keyboard is displayed, we sometimes get an unwanted shift of the entire page up.

What can be done? Is it possible to block the change of our page when the software keyboard is displayed?

Comment: You use the Android/iOS-Keyboard, or the `QVirtualKeyboard`?

Comment: We use Android / iOS-Keyboard.